How to load Mobile version of site as external webpage in my html page
I want to load a mobile view responsive website into in my HTML page.
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 

<head> 
    <title>full screen iframe</title> 
</head> 
<frameset rows="100%,*"> 
    <frame src= 
"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames"> 
        <noframes> 

            <body> 

            </body> 
        </noframes> 
</frameset> 

</html> 


with this i'm able to load but i want to load design as we open wikipedia in mobile version.

Setting iframe size similar to a mobile device should work.
<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/" class="mobile-view"></iframe>

You also need to define mobile-view class in your css, or your html.
 <style>
 .mobile-view {
   width: 375px;
   height: 667px;
   border: none;
 }
 </style>

